# Leer Parents y childs de JSON y generar objetos a partir de ellos

Tags: c#, json, jsonobject

Estoy tratando de convertir este JSON en objetos con ciertos atributos existentes en JSON, actualmente recibo este JSON como un string.
He podido contabilizar la cantidad de elementos existentes o consultar un único atributo, pero no encuentro la forma de crear un objeto sin conocer el nombre exacto del padre. Este JSON es una respuesta de la API de Philips Hue.

```
"3":{
   "state":{
      "on":true,
      "bri":254,
      "hue":27306,
      "sat":140,
      "effect":"none",
      "xy":[
         0.2637,
         0.5264
      ],
      "ct":153,
      "alert":"select",
      "colormode":"hs",
      "mode":"homeautomation",
      "reachable":false
   },
   "swupdate":{
      "state":"noupdates",
      "lastinstall":"2020-01-30T12:22:09"
   },
   "type":"Extended color light",
   "name":"Hue color lamp 1",
   "modelid":"LCT015",
   "manufacturername":"Signify Netherlands B.V.",
   "productname":"Hue color lamp",
   "capabilities":{
      "certified":true,
      "control":{
         "mindimlevel":1000,
         "maxlumen":806,
         "colorgamuttype":"C",
         "colorgamut":[
            [
               0.6915,
               0.3083
            ],
            [
               0.17,
               0.7
            ],
            [
               0.1532,
               0.0475
            ]
         ],
         "ct":{
            "min":153,
            "max":500
         }
      },
      "streaming":{
         "renderer":true,
         "proxy":true
      }
   },
   "config":{
      "archetype":"sultanbulb",
      "function":"mixed",
      "direction":"omnidirectional",
      "startup":{
         "mode":"safety",
         "configured":true
      }
   },
   "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:04:0c:5b:8b-0b",
   "swversion":"1.46.13_r26312",
   "swconfigid":"52E3234B",
   "productid":"Philips-LCT015-1-A19ECLv5"
},
"5":{
   "state":{
      "on":true,
      "bri":236,
      "alert":"select",
      "mode":"homeautomation",
      "reachable":false
   },
   "swupdate":{
      "state":"noupdates",
      "lastinstall":"2020-02-21T12:27:34"
   },
   "type":"Dimmable light",
   "name":"Hue white lamp 1",
   "modelid":"LWB010",
   "manufacturername":"Signify Netherlands B.V.",
   "productname":"Hue white lamp",
   "capabilities":{
      "certified":true,
      "control":{
         "mindimlevel":2000,
         "maxlumen":806
      },
      "streaming":{
         "renderer":false,
         "proxy":false
      }
   },
   "config":{
      "archetype":"classicbulb",
      "function":"functional",
      "direction":"omnidirectional",
      "startup":{
         "mode":"safety",
         "configured":true
      }
   },
   "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:04:a5:ab:fc-0b",
   "swversion":"1.46.13_r26312",
   "swconfigid":"322BB2EC",
   "productid":"Philips-LWB010-1-A19DLv4"
}
}
```

Los nombres de los Parents ("3") y ("5") se generan automáticamente, no puedo crear un objeto estableciendo como parent un nombre específico, este va variando. Eso si, siempre son números.

Mi idea es crear objetos con estos atributos:

```
public class Light
{
    public string lightNumber { get; set; }
    public string lightOn { get; set; }
    public string lightHue { get; set; }
    public string lightBri { get; set; }
}
```

Quisiera generar tantos objetos como elementos parents existen en el JSON y que se almacene los datos on, bri, hue y el número del parent como atributos del objeto.

Estoy utlizando C# y la librería Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cuando tengas esos valores dinámicos (el "3" y el "5"), lo puedes deserializar vía  `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`. Te paso un ejemplo de una aplicación de consola el cual lee un fichero `data.json`con el contenido que has mostrado y luego lo deserializa. He generado las clases correspondientes a tu fichero para poder deserializar.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public State State { get; set; }
        public Swupdate Swupdate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Modelid { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturername { get; set; }
        public string Productname { get; set; }
        public Capabilities Capabilities { get; set; }
        public Config Config { get; set; }
        public string Uniqueid { get; set; }
        public string Swversion { get; set; }
        public string Swconfigid { get; set; }
        public string Productid { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Capabilities
    {
        public bool Certified { get; set; }
        public Control Control { get; set; }
        public Streaming Streaming { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Control
    {
        public long Mindimlevel { get; set; }
        public long Maxlumen { get; set; }
        public string Colorgamuttype { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> Colorgamut { get; set; }
        public Ct Ct { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Ct
    {
        public long Min { get; set; }
        public long Max { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Streaming
    {
        public bool Renderer { get; set; }
        public bool Proxy { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Config
    {
        public string Archetype { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public Startup Startup { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public string Mode { get; set; }
        public bool Configured { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class State
    {
        public bool On { get; set; }
        public long Bri { get; set; }
        public long? Hue { get; set; }
        public long? Sat { get; set; }
        public string Effect { get; set; }
        public List<double> Xy { get; set; }
        public long? Ct { get; set; }
        public string Alert { get; set; }
        public string Colormode { get; set; }
        public string Mode { get; set; }
        public bool Reachable { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Swupdate
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Lastinstall { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonToDeserialize = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data.json");
            var dataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyClass>>(jsonToDeserialize);

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Luego navegas a través del diccionario por cada elemento y voila!

Comment: Buenas Sergio, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ¿me podrías dar un ejemplo de como navegar dentro del diccionario? Estoy aplicando tu ejemplo y tengo la duda de como llegar hasta los atributos.

Comment: Nada, no es necesario Sergio, he podido encontrar la forma. Muchisimas gracias. Ahora me resta averiguar como obtener el nombre del elemento padre. El "3" y "5". Pero de nuevo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo creo que tienes el JSON en mal formato, en la API prueba con un

> header accept --> application/abas.objects.simple+json

Luego tienes que generar una clase de ese JSON, para hacerlo pon en google json to "el lenguaje que uses". Una vez tienes la clase creada (voy a poner el ejemplo en C#) tienes que descargar e importar Newtonsoft. Después coges tu string con el JSON y lo deserializas.
RootObject es la clase generada automaticamente.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string);
```

Después de eso la variable obj es tu JSON en formato objecto.